# Grails make upper case each word in the line

Tags: grails

I want to make in a line each word first character as upper case and remaning character as lower case. the following code prints same as orginal string. how can make this to work?

```
def name = "hello world grails"

        println  name.split(" +").each{
             it[0]?.toUpperCase()+it[1..-1]?.toLowerCase()
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `capitalize()` method which was added to Groovy in 1.7.3 release:

```
def name = "hello world grails"
def splitted = name.split("\\s+").collect { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }
println splitted
```

If you want to have a String:

```
println splitted.inject('') { accumulator, current -> accumulator + current + ' ' }.trim()
```

There is also a problem with your code. Using `.each {...}` will not 'convert' the elements in resulting list e.g.

```
def list = ["Asdf", "XCVB"]
def ret = list.each { return it.toLowerCase() }
println ret == list // true
ret = list.collect { return it.toLowerCase() }
println ret == list // false
```

Comment: hi, why your code addss command and brackets like this '[Hello, World, Grails]' when we print

Comment: @sfgroups because `splitted` variable is of type list. Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will done your job:

```
 ​def name = "hello world grails"

 def newName = ""
 name.split(" ").each { word ->
    newName += word[0].toUpperCase() + word[1..(word.size()-1)].toLowerCase()+" "
 }

 println newName​
```

Comment: your code works, but i like @Xeon code. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
def requiredString = org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils.capitalizeFully('i AM gRooT') // yields 'I Am Groot'
```

You would need to include, as a dependency, Apache Commons Lang.